# Parsing XML file in Swift (Xcode v 7.0.1) and retrieving values from dictionary

Tags: xml, swift, google-maps, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse an XML file in Swift and I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding how the NSMutableDictionary works in storing values from elements.

The XML file looks like this,

```
<coord2 count="6">
  <markers>
    <marker>
      <lat>36.99058167</lat>
      <lng>-122.06620333</lng>
      <timestamp>1444931620</timestamp>
      <route>LOOP</route>
      <id>7855</id>
      <predictions>
      ,4,5,,6,7,,,,10,,,11,,11,,13,15,,14,,,16,,,0,,,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
      </predictions>
      <update_seconds>10</update_seconds>
      <index>4</index>
    </marker>
    <marker>
      <lat>36.99296</lat>
      <lng>-122.06517333</lng>
      <timestamp>1444934786</timestamp>
      <route>UPPER CAMPUS</route>
      <id>7860</id>
      <predictions>
      15,,,14,,,13,12,11,,10,9,,8,,7,,,6,,5,4,,3,2,,1,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
      </predictions>
      <update_seconds>10</update_seconds>
      <index>4</index>
    </marker>
  </markers>
  <curr_time>1444931622</curr_time>
</coord2>
```

The way I'm attempting to parse the XML file is with the following code that I found from a tutorial at 
http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/xml-parsing-using-nsxmlparse-swift

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController, NSXMLParserDelegate {

    var parser = NSXMLParser()
    var posts = NSMutableArray()
    var elements = NSMutableDictionary()
    var element = NSString()
    var route = NSMutableString()
    var timestamp = NSMutableString()

    func beginParsing()
    {
        posts = []
        parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL:(NSURL(string:"http://xmfile.xml"))!)!
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.parse()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        beginParsing()

        print("The route is")
        let t = elements["route"]!
        print(t)
        print("The timestamp is")
        let u = elements["timestamp"]!
        print(u)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // didStartElement
    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String])
    {
        element = elementName
        if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("marker")
        {
            elements = NSMutableDictionary()
            elements = [:]
            route = NSMutableString()
            route = ""
            timestamp = NSMutableString()
            timestamp = ""
        }
    }

    // foundCharacters
    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String)
    {
        if element.isEqualToString("route") {
            route.appendString(string)
        } else if element.isEqualToString("timestamp") {
            timestamp.appendString(string)
        }
    }

    // didEndElement
    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?)
    {
        if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("marker") {
            if !route.isEqual(nil) {
                elements.setObject(route, forKey: "route")
            }
            if !timestamp.isEqual(nil) {
                elements.setObject(timestamp, forKey: "timestamp")
            }
            posts.addObject(elements)
        }
    }

}
```

Right now I'm only focusing on the "route" and "timestamp" elements just to gain an understanding of how parsing works. The output I get when I

```
let t = elements["route"]!
print(t)
print("previous is route")
let u = elements["timestamp"]!
print(u)
print("previous is timestamp")
```

is always the value of the **last** elements that have those names in the XML file. So, for the example XML file I provided the output of the 6 lines of code above would be

**The route is**
**UPPER CAMPUS**

**The timestamp is**
**1444934786**

I want to be able to distinguish between the multiple "**marker**" elements in the XML file and retrieve the values of elements within marker. In other words, be able to get the values of elements within the first marker also, not just the last one. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you require to use NSMutableDictionary / NSMutableArray or would creating classes to represent Coord2 / Marker be an option? Reason I ask is that if you can use custom classes, you can use another approach to cleanly parse your XML, and have more manageable code...

Comment: Thanks for the response. Right now, I'm open to suggestions. I'm fairly new to Swift so I'm learning as I go. How would I accomplish this with custom classes?

Comment: Alright... I've put up an answer for you; please check it out below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

**NOTE**
I've put the [whole thing in a gist](https://gist.github.com/BenziAhamed/60eddd34db29f6d64e29) which you can copy and paste into a playground.

---

Let's look at a simple example to get a start:

```
let xml = "<coord2 count=\"3\">"
+ "<markers>"
    + "<marker>"
    + "<item>marker1</item>"
    + "</marker>"
    + "<marker>"
    + "<item>marker2</item>"
    + "<lat>36</lat>"
    + "</marker>"
+ "</markers>"
+ "</coord2>"
```

A bit narrowed down, but Markers can have a item name (string) and lat value (int). A Coord2 will have an array of Markers, and a count (int) attribute.

To parse the above with custom classes, here's one approach.

First create a ParserBase class that does some ground work for us, namely accumulating foundCharacters so that it can be easily used by sub classes.
Also (more importantly) it has a `parent` property which is used to hold references to the parent container class [this is used for the way in which we will be parsing XML].

```
// Simple base class that is used to consume foundCharacters
// via the parser

class ParserBase : NSObject, NSXMLParserDelegate  {

    var currentElement:String = ""
    var foundCharacters = ""
    weak var parent:ParserBase? = nil

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {

        currentElement = elementName
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        self.foundCharacters += string
    }

}
```

Since **coord2** is our root tag, we will create a class that will map to that tag - it represents the root object, has an array of Markers, a count property, and is also the root delegate object for the XMLParser.

```
// Represents a coord2 tag
// It has a count attribute
// and a collection of markers

class Coord2 : ParserBase {


    var count = 0
    var markers = [Marker]()



    override func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {

        print("processing <\(elementName)> tag from Coord")

        if elementName == "coord2" {

            // if we are processing a coord2 tag, we are at the root
            // of this example
            // extract the count value and set it
            if let c = Int(attributeDict["count"]!) {
                self.count = c
            }
        }

        // if we found a marker tag, delegate further responsibility
        // to parsing to a new instance of Marker

        if elementName == "marker" {
            let marker = Marker()
            self.markers.append(marker)

            // push responsibility
            parser.delegate = marker

            // let marker know who we are
            // so that once marker is done XML processing
            // it can return parsing responsibility back
            marker.parent = self
        }
    }


}
```

The Marker class is as follows:

```
class Marker : ParserBase {

    var item = ""
    var lat = 0

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {

        print("processing <\(elementName)> tag from Marker")

        // if we finished an item tag, the ParserBase parent
        // would have accumulated the found characters
        // so just assign that to our item variable
        if elementName == "item" {
            self.item = foundCharacters
        }

            // similarly for lat tags
            // convert the lat to an int for example
        else if elementName == "lat" {
            if let l = Int(foundCharacters) {
                self.lat = l
            }
        }

        // if we reached the </marker> tag, we do not
        // have anything further to do, so delegate
        // parsing responsibility to parent
        else if elementName == "marker" {
            parser.delegate = self.parent
        }

        // reset found characters
        foundCharacters = ""
    }

}
```

Now on to parsing, extracting info, and printing something.

```
let xmlData = xml.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
let parser = NSXMLParser(data: xmlData)

let coord = Coord2()
parser.delegate = coord

parser.parse()


print("coord has a count attribute of \(coord.count)")
print("coord has \(coord.markers.count) markers")

for marker in coord.markers {
    print("marker item = \(marker.item) and lat = \(marker.lat)")
}
```

which outputs the following:

```
coord has a count attribute of 3
coord has 2 markers
marker item = marker1 and lat = 0
marker item = marker2 and lat = 36
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the help @Benzi. One more question. Where do I put the URL for the XML file? I don't have the XML file locally on my machine. Also, do I put the last block of code inside my `override func viewDidLoad() { .. }` function?

Comment: Yes you can put that last block of code in `viewDidLoad`... As for the URL, how were you working with the parser so far? If you had constructed it with something like `parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL:(NSURL(string:"http://xmfile.xml"))!)!` like that, then use that in place of the corresponding line in the last block. (I was using a Playground, so had to have the XML in a string.)

Comment: Awesome. Mostly everything is working except for casting the String to a Double. I see in your response you're casting it to an Int. I need to cast to Double but it isn't working. I'm trying `var lat = ""`, `var lati = 0.0`, `self.lat = foundCharacters`, `self.lati = (self.lat as NSString).doubleValue`. The value of `self.lat` is "36.97728" but `self.lati` will remain 0.0

Comment: If you are using Swift 2.x, Double has an initializer that takes in a string. Something like 
`let s = "34.223";
let doubleValue = Double(s) ?? 0 // try to make a double else its 0`

Comment: I think `foundCharacters` is doing something to the string "36.97728". When I do `var lat = ""; self.lat = foundCharacters; let doubleFromlat = Double(self.lat)`, `doubleFormat` gets assigned `nil`. I've been reading that this happens when the string you're trying to cast as a Double can't be cast. For example, `Double("abc")` will be `nil`.

Comment: I've notice that when I `self.lat = foundCharacters; print(self.lat)` I get the output: **    36.97728** (i.e. 4 spaces get printed before "36.97728" along with a new line right above) Could this be causing the issue?

Comment: Yeah those * characters will be bad. Any idea where those are coming from?

Comment: Ok * is spaces... in the parser base class try foundCaracters = string instead of += string. Don't have access to my laptop to check anything right now

Comment: THAT WORKED! Now, is `coord.markers` and array? How can I distinguish the different `markers` within the XML file? Can I do `coord.marker[0]`, `coord.marker[1]`, `coord.marker[2]`, etc.? THANK YOU.

Comment: Yes its an array. If its all in place now, would you mind marking my answer as accepted - might be helpful to others down the line as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Benzi! I'd give you 1000 points if I could. The XML file I'm reading is dynamic (refreshes every 10 seconds). I am using NSTimer() to rerun my code every 10 seconds. For some reason after about 5 reruns, my program crashes. Any ideas what may be causing this? The function I'm rerunning every time with NSTimer() is viewDidload().

Comment: Not too sure about that one. Maybe some sort of memory allocation problem?

Answer (score 4):

I have used Class Created below To get Dictionary From XML data.

https://github.com/Bhaavik/BDXmlParser

You need To add that class and just call Below Function for Dictionary response

let objXmlParser = BbXmlParser()
  let  dictResponse  =  objXmlParser.getdictionaryFromXmlData(data!)
                        print(dictResponse)
And here You go with dictionary. :)

Comment: If a question is a duplicate of another, **flag** the question as duplicate instead of answering. Do not post the same answer multiple times anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks For Your Suggestion !It is my first answer and I am learning Stuffs :)

Comment: Then you should read the [tour] and see the various articles in the [help]. It will help you make better answers (I mean, answers which follow the site's guidelines). :)

Comment: Correlation != causation. You don't know who has voted: don't assume it's the person talking to you...

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 2.2:

Assume your xml file is located in any where in your pc and let the xml file is :

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://.dtd" >
```

```
<packages>
    <package name="packageone" />
</packages>

<test name="testOne">
    <classes>
        <class name="TestClassOne">
            <methods>
                <include name="test_480" />
                <include name="test_481" />
                <include name="test_482" />
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="testOne">
    <classes>
        <class name="TestClassOne">
            <methods>
                <include name="test_111" />
                <include name="test_112" />
                <include name="test_113" />
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

So, if you want to read only the test cases name from this xml,use the below code:

```
import Foundation

class XmlParsing : NSObject, NSXMLParserDelegate {

var element:String = "default"
var testCaseName = [String]()

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {

    if(elementName == "include"){

        //you can store the data in an array or any other way, if you want to use it in anywhere.
        //testCaseName.append(attributeDict["name"]!) // this is used to store the test cases name
        print(attributeDict["name"]!)
    }
  }    

}
```

Now call the function like:

```
let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "xml-file-location" ).URLByAppendingPathComponent("test.xml")

var fileContent = try NSString(contentsOfURL: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String

let data = fileContent.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) //convert string to data for xml parsing

let xmlParser = NSXMLParser(data: data!) //create xml parser

let xmlRead = XmlParsing() // create the object of that class where function is declared.

xmlParser.delegate = xmlRead //use that object to delegate
xmlParser.parse() // parse the xml
```

when

```
xmlParser.parse()
```

is called, than parser function is called and do the necessary job.The output is:

```
test_480
test_481
test_482
test_111
test_112
test_113
```

One more important thing is parser has overloaded function. you can use them as your requirement.

For example, if you need to read any

```
commented node
```

from your xml file, use the below parser function in the XmlParsing  class:

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundComment comment: String) {

   print(comment)
}
```

This is the link to find api details:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSXMLParserDelegate/parser:foundComment: